# woocommerce add custom post type to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and i created a custom post type that has to be treated as a product and user may add to cart. I followed this tutorial 
http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/
and made sure my price field meta key is “_price”
but it didn't work.

when I tried to add this code to functions.php

```
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price = null,$post = null){
if ($post->post->post_type === 'aytam'){
    $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "_price", true);
    }

return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,1);
add_action( 'init', 'reigel_woocommerce_get_price' );
```

didn't work either

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version 3.0.* Woocommcerce used to hard check the `$post_type === 'product'` You can override it. You could find a complete solution [here](https://www.octocs.com/how-to-integrate-custom-post-type-in-woocommerce-and-update-pricing/).

```
class My_Product_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT implements WC_Object_Data_Store_Interface, WC_Product_Data_Store_Interface {

    
    /**
     * Method to read a product from the database.
     * @param WC_Product
     */
    public function read( &$product ) {
        $product->set_defaults();

        if ( ! $product->get_id() || ! ( $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() ) ) || 'product' !== $post_object->post_type ) {
            //throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid product.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        $id = $product->get_id();

        $product->set_props( array(
            'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
            'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
            'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
            'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
            'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
            'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
            'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
            'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
            'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
            'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
        ) );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );
    }

    
}
```

Then include this file via hook;

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'my_woocommerce_data_stores' );`

```
function my_woocommerce_data_stores( $stores ) {

    require_once PLUGIN_PATH . '/includes/classes/class-data-store-cpt.php';
    $stores['product'] = 'MY_Product_Data_Store_CPT';

    return $stores;
}
```

Use this filter to provide the price from custom meta;

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'my_woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function my_woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    if (get_post_type($product->get_id()) == 'book' ) {
        $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'price', true );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Now if you try adding to cart using url param `add-to-cart=[POST_ID]` like http://localhost/wordpress/cart/?add-to-cart=244 will add the item to cart.

You can also use button to add to cart.

```
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
            <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1"  />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 5):

been tackling with this and since the above code didn't work, I went ahead and made a working version. Note that this code works with **Woocommerce 3.6.2** (at least) and is intended to make it work with custom post type **industry-ad** , but you can change to what you desire

```
class IA_Woo_Product extends WC_Product  {

    protected $post_type = 'industry-ad';

    public function get_type() {
        return 'industry-ad';
    }

    public function __construct( $product = 0 ) {
        $this->supports[]   = 'ajax_add_to_cart';

        parent::__construct( $product );


    }
    // maybe overwrite other functions from WC_Product

}

class IA_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT {

    public function read( &$product ) { // this is required
        $product->set_defaults();
        $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() );

        if ( ! $product->get_id() || ! $post_object || 'industry-ad' !== $post_object->post_type ) {

            throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid product.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        $product->set_props(
            array(
                'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
                'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
                'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
                'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
                'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
                'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
                'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
                'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
                'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
                'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
            )
        );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );
    }

    // maybe overwrite other functions from WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT

}


class IA_WC_Order_Item_Product extends WC_Order_Item_Product {
    public function set_product_id( $value ) {
        if ( $value > 0 && 'industry-ad' !== get_post_type( absint( $value ) ) ) {
            $this->error( 'order_item_product_invalid_product_id', __( 'Invalid product ID', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }
        $this->set_prop( 'product_id', absint( $value ) );
    }

}




function IA_woocommerce_data_stores( $stores ) {
    // the search is made for product-$post_type so note the required 'product-' in key name
    $stores['product-industry-ad'] = 'IA_Data_Store_CPT';
    return $stores;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'IA_woocommerce_data_stores' , 11, 1 );


function IA_woo_product_class( $class_name ,  $product_type ,  $product_id ) {
    if ($product_type == 'industry-ad')
        $class_name = 'IA_Woo_Product';
    return $class_name; 
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_class','IA_woo_product_class',25,3 );



function my_woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ($product->get_type() == 'industry-ad' ) {
        $price = 10;  // or get price how ever you see fit     
    }
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','my_woocommerce_product_get_price',20,2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'my_woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );



// required function for allowing posty_type to be added; maybe not the best but it works
function IA_woo_product_type($false,$product_id) { 
    if ($false === false) { // don't know why, but this is how woo does it
        global $post;
        // maybe redo it someday?!
        if (is_object($post) && !empty($post)) { // post is set
            if ($post->post_type == 'industry-ad' && $post->ID == $product_id) 
                return 'industry-ad';
            else {
                $product = get_post( $product_id );
                if (is_object($product) && !is_wp_error($product)) { // post not set but it's a industry-ad
                    if ($product->post_type == 'industry-ad') 
                        return 'industry-ad';
                } // end if 
            }    

        } else if(wp_doing_ajax()) { // has post set (usefull when adding using ajax)
            $product_post = get_post( $product_id );
            if ($product_post->post_type == 'industry-ad') 
                return 'industry-ad';
        } else { 
            $product = get_post( $product_id );
            if (is_object($product) && !is_wp_error($product)) { // post not set but it's a industry-ad
                if ($product->post_type == 'industry-ad') 
                    return 'industry-ad';
            } // end if 

        } // end if  // end if 



    } // end if 
    return false;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_type_query','IA_woo_product_type',12,2 );

function IA_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item_object($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {

    $product                    = $values['data'];
    if ($product->get_type() == 'industry-ad') {
        return new IA_WC_Order_Item_Product();
    } // end if 
    return $item ;
}   
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item_object', 'IA_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item_object', 20, 4 );

function cod_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item($item,$cart_item_key,$values,$order) {
    if ($values['data']->get_type() == 'industry-ad') {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_industry-ad', 'yes' ); // add a way to recognize custom post type in ordered items
        return;
    } // end if 

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'cod_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 20, 4 );

function IA_woocommerce_get_order_item_classname($classname, $item_type, $id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $is_IA = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id = {$id} AND meta_key = '_industry-ad'");


    if ('yes' === $is_IA) { // load the new class if the item is our custom post
        $classname = 'IA_WC_Order_Item_Product';
    } // end if 
    return $classname;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_classname', 'IA_woocommerce_get_order_item_classname', 20, 3 );
```

Answer (score 3):

WooCommerce provides hooks that recognizes CPT as product upto checkout.

Step 1. Use this hook that helps to extend data store class and override product post types

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'my_cpt_woocommerce_data_stores' );
function my_cpt_woocommerce_data_stores( $stores ) {
    $stores['product'] = 'My_Cpt_Product_Data_Store';

    return $stores;
}
```

Step 2. Use that class to extend WooCommerce Data Store class

```
class My_Cpt_Product_Data_Store extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT implements WC_Object_Data_Store_Interface, WC_Product_Data_Store_Interface {

    public function read( &$product ) {

        $product->set_defaults();

        if ( !$product->get_id() || !( $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() ) ) || !in_array( $post_object->post_type, ['my_cpt', 'product'] ) ) {
            throw new Exception( esc_html__( 'Invalid product.', 'text-domain' ) );
        }

        $product->set_id( $post_object->ID );

        $product->set_props( [
            'product_id'        => $post_object->ID,
            'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
            'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
            'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
            'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
            'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
            'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
            'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
            'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
            'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
            'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
        ] );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );
    }

    /**
     * Get the product type based on product ID.
     */
    public function get_product_type( $product_id ) {

        $post_type = get_post_type( $product_id );

        if ( 'product_variation' === $post_type ) {
            return 'variation';
        } elseif ( in_array( $post_type, ['my_cpt', 'product'] ) ) {
            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_type' );
            return !empty( $terms ) ? sanitize_title( current( $terms )->name ) : 'my_cpt';
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Step 3. Return price dynamically from your CPT meta value

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'my_cpt_woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function my_cpt_woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    if ( get_post_type( $product_id ) == 'my_cpt' ) {
        $price = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'price', true );
        $price = isset( $price ) ? ( floatval( $price ) ) : 0;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Step 4. Use the post id to add the post to cart

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php the_ID();?>" />
    <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

**Note:** If you've done till this step, then the post will be added to cart and WooCommerce will recognize it as cart item up to checkout process. But WooCommerce won't recognize it as an order item after checkout is done. To make it available as an order item, we need to follow some more steps.

Step 1. Use your custom class to extend WooCommerce product class and add your CPT

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'my_cpt_woo_product_class');
function my_cpt_woo_product_class( $class_name, $product_type, $product_id ) {
    if ($product_type == 'my_cpt') {
        $class_name = 'My_Cpt_Woo_Product';
    }

    return $class_name;
}

class My_Cpt_Woo_Product extends WC_Product {
    protected $post_type = 'my_cpt';

    public function get_type() {
        return 'my_cpt';
    }

    public function __construct( $product = 0 ) {
        $this->supports[] = 'ajax_add_to_cart';
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }
    // maybe overwrite other functions from WC_Product
}
```

Step 2. Make sure your CPT is recognized as Product when WooCommerce tries to get product class

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_classname', 'my_cpt_woocommerce_get_order_item_classname', 20, 3 );
function my_cpt_woocommerce_get_order_item_classname($class_name, $item_type, $id) {

    if (get_post_type( $id ) == 'my_cpt' {
        $class_name = 'My_Cpt_WC_Order_Item_Product';
    }

    return $class_name;
}

class My_Cpt_WC_Order_Item_Product extends WC_Order_Item_Product {
    public function set_product_id( $value ) {
        if ( $value > 0 && 'my_cpt' !== get_post_type( absint( $value ) ) ) {
            $this->error( 'order_item_product_invalid_product_id', __( 'Invalid product ID', 'text-domain' ) );
        }
        $this->set_prop( 'product_id', absint( $value ) );
    }
}
```

Step 3. Make sure your CPT is queryable as WooCommerce Product

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_type_query', 'my_cpt_woo_product_type', 12, 2 );
function my_cpt_woo_product_type($false, $product_id) {
    if ($false === false) { // don't know why, but this is how woo does it
        global $post;

        // maybe redo it someday?!
        if ( !empty($post) && is_object($post) ) { // post is set
            if ($post->post_type == 'my_cpt' && $post->ID == $product_id) {
                return 'my_cpt';
            } else {
                $product = get_post( $product_id );
                if ( is_object($product) && !is_wp_error($product) ) {
                    if ($product->post_type == 'my_cpt') return 'my_cpt';
                }
            }
        } else if( wp_doing_ajax() ) { // has post set (useful when adding using ajax)
            $product_post = get_post( $product_id );
            if ($product_post->post_type == 'my_cpt') return 'my_cpt';
        } else {
            $product = get_post( $product_id );
            if ( is_object($product) && !is_wp_error($product) ) {
                if ($product->post_type == 'my_cpt') return 'my_cpt';
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Step 4. Finally, your CPT should be queryable as as order line item

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item_object', 'my_cpt_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item_object', 20, 4 );
function my_cpt_woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item_object($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    $product = $values['data'];

    if ($product->get_type() == 'my_cpt') {
        return new My_Cpt_WC_Order_Item_Product();
    }

    return $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a meta key which is `not _price`, you can add a filter to `woocommerce_get_price` shown below.

```
  add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
    function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
        if ($post->post->post_type === 'post') // change this to your post type
            $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "price", true); // your price meta key is price
        return $price;
    }
```

Comment: didn't work for me, I used a custom product type instead. but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Didn't work for me, as in latest version 3.0.* there are lot stuff changed. Still looking  for a solution.